# Use python to parse text in DataFrame with regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I will represent my problem as a simplified example.

I have a pandas DataFrame
I would like to create a new column whose content comes from an existing column, call it "columnA", whose values are long strings of text.

suppose a value in df["columnA"] is "Hello world the sky is blue and the grass is green"

I want the new column to be only the words from columnA that start with "T" or "G"

So the corresponding value in our new column would be: "the the grass green"

(in my real example, everything is uppercase)

I've tried using findall() in various fashions and list comprehensions. I've been able to return the first occurrence but struggle to efficiently get all occurences.

Comment: Actual runnable code to reproduce the problem would help us give you a result you can actually use.

Comment: Maybe 
`df['newcolname'] = df['columnA'].apply(lambda x: re.findall("[GT]\w+",x))`

Comment: To go with @ThePhoton 's comment, see [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern `\b([tg]\w+)\b` in `pandas.Series.str.findall` call:

```
import re

df['new_col'] = df['columnA'].str.findall(r'\b[tg]\w+\b', 
                                          flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.join(' ')
```

---

```
                                             columnA              new_col
0  Hello world the sky is blue and the grass is g...  the the grass green
```

Comment: Also, depending on what kind of "words" OP is looking for, they might rather use `\w*` instead of `\w+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columnA.str.findall(r'\b[tbTB]\w+').str.join(' ')
```

This code performs a string operation on the values in a column called columnA in a Pandas DataFrame df. Specifically, it finds all occurrences of words that start with either 't', 'b', 'T', or 'B' and are followed by one or more words or numbers including hyphen

fillall functions return a list which is why I used .str.join(" ") method to covert the list into string.